# Android Default tone picker issue (default tone with notifications and alarm)

Tags: android, uri, picker, ringtone

I don't know if it is a stupid question with easy solution. I have a ringtone picker that shows the default ringtone option (for Notifications). Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

And then I catch the result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent mRingtone) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                notifToneUri = mRingtone.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri);
                Log.d(TAG,"Uri = " + notifToneUri.toString() + " and title = " + ringtone.getTitle(this));
            }
        break;
    } 
}
```

**An weird thing happens**, if I select the option "Default notification tone", the uri should be:  *content://settings/system/notification_sound* but the uri is *content://settings/system/ringtone* (which is the default value of the ringtone, not the notification). It happens the same with the Default alarm tone.

I solved like this:

```
if (notifToneUri.equals(Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI)){
    notifToneUri = Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI;
}
```

Ok this works... But I would like to know if there is a better way or there is something I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think you're retrieving the `Uri` correctly. Here's an example to follow:

**Launch the `RingtoneManager`**

```
final Intent ringtone = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
ringtone.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
ringtone.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
ringtone.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI,
            RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
startActivityForResult(ringtone, 0);
```

**Retrieve the `Uri` and title in `Activity.onActivityResult`**

```
if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    final Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
    final Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri);
    // Get your title here `ringtone.getTitle(this)`
}
```

You can see [here in the source for `Ringtone`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/Ringtone.java#L107), that the prefix is only added when the authhority of the `Uri` is equal to `Settings.AUTHORITY` and never `MediaStore.AUTHORITY`.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I didn't write all my code. I am doing the same you propose (for launching the picker and pick up the result). But I am having the issue I described. If I select in the picker "Default notification tone", instead of receive the correct uri, I am receiving the uri of the default RINGER tone.

Comment: I made an edit. You need to include the `RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI` as an extra.

Comment: Yes! This was the trick, I thought that if you put TYPE_NOTIFICATION and EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT to true would be enough but it's not. Thank you very much.